# Right syntax of NavigateUrl Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a new to `ASP.Net`. Hope you dont mind if my problem is so simple with some people.

In my `code.aspx` page, I have a HyperLink:

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">
```

In `code.aspx.cs`, I want the HyperLink1 navigate to : Show.asp page with an id

Like:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl="'id'/~Show.asp?id={0}";//it seems the syntax is wrong.
```

Can you tell me a right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what how the URL should be formulated. You could simply use the markup:

```
NavigateUrl="/url.aspx?id=1"
```

But that's not dynamic in the slightest and could well just use a primitive `<a>` element. Although it does facilitate changing it dynamically in the code-behind if you need to, say on PostBack.

You can also just set the whole thing in code-behind:

```
link.NavigateUrl = string.Format("/url.aspx?id={0}", id);
```

Otherwise you could provide the format in the markup and alter it in code-behind (often useful, I find, in order to give clarity to the link by just looking at the markup - designers etc. need not find the code-behind reference where the page-part of the URL is defined in order to see where it goes):

```
NavigateUrl="/url.aspx?id={0}"
```

Then change it in code-behind using:

```
link.NavigateUrl = string.Format(link.NavigateUrl, id);
```

Of course you also do not need to use `string.Format`, you could concatenate the string "natively" using the operator (i.e. `"/url.aspx?id=" + id.ToString()`).

There are also other ways, such as using inline script in a repeater to access the data item, but I won't give an example as I would very rarely advocate this (only doing so in circumstances where it is absolutely necessary).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = String.Format("id/~Show.asp?id={0}", myID);
```

where `myID` is the value that you want to replace `{0}` with. As a side note, are you sure the extension is not `aspx` instead of `asp`? ASP relates to [Active Server Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) whereas `aspx` is the extension from `ASP.NET` compiled pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("Show.asp?id={0}", id);
```

This assumes `id` is a variable which holds the value which would be passed.

Comment: Thanks, it is so simple to use ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = 35;
    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/Show.asp?id=" + id;
}
```